# How can I switch between multiple video stream with ExoPlayer?

Tags: vlc, android

I have seen a .mp4 movie file with two video streams. The first one is the trailer of the movie with 10 minutes of movie length, and the second one is the whole movie of 2 hours.

Can I access the two movie streams separately based on some conditions in Android programming with the help of ExoPlayer or VLC libraries? If you can suggest other libraries, I would be happy to get some help.